# Strange output from program

Tags: c++

I have written the following code, but the output is displaying weird values along the lines of `011512EE`. I have no idea where this is coming from or how to fix it.

[image: code]

Comment: Do not post your code as image. Please post your code as text directly in your question.

Comment: Please post code within the question AND your output.

Comment: My apologies, first time ever using this website.

Comment: **UAFD**  Use a Debugger.  Set a breakpoint, Examine your variables, Step through your code.

Answer (score 5):

You are printing the *address* of the functions.

I guess you want to *call* the functions and print *their return values*.

Try this

```
cout << "\nThe surface area of the prism is: " << calculateSurfaceArea(length, width, height) << endl;
cout << "The volume of the prism is: " << calculateVolume(length, width, height) << endl;
```

instead of

```
cout << "\nThe surface area of the prism is: " << calculateSurfaceArea << endl;
cout << "The volume of the prism is: " << calculateVolume << endl;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I'm a beginner and struggling with functions. Also sorry again for posting the code as a picture.